# Martingale: how do they simplify betting summation

Tags: probability

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} B \cdot 2^{i-1}=B\left(2^{n}-1\right)
$$
How can I go from the summation to $B(2^n-1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a general fact that

$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} r^{i - 1} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} r^{i} = \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$

Now select $r = 2$.

---

Proving this is a step in analyzing [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and the above claim can be proven by induction or any number of other means.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I need to study geometric series a bit more...